# Error in running Haskell code

Tags: haskell

I'm new to programming and Haskell, so appologies if this is elementary.

I'm having trouble running the program below, but I'm not sure if it's a program error or if I don't know how to use `ghci`.

I have written a program that behaves likes `last`, but returns the second to last item in a list instead.

My code is

```
main :: IO ()
main = return ()    
lastButOne::[a]->a
lastButOne xs = if length xs == 2
                then head xs
                else lastButOne (tail xs)
```

The program compiles just fine, but I can't seem to find a way to run it without giving me an error.

The textbook gives an example of running a program which emulates `drop` by doing the following in `ghci`

```
ghci> :load myDrop.hs
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
ghci> myDrop 3 "asdfg"
"fg"
```

However, when I load my `lastButOne.hs` and attempt to give the program input I get the following

```
Prelude> :load lastButOne.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( lastButOne.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
*Main> lastButOne [a,b,c,d,e,f]

<interactive>:2:13: error: Variable not in scope: a

<interactive>:2:15: error: Variable not in scope: b

<interactive>:2:17: error: Variable not in scope: c

<interactive>:2:19: error: Variable not in scope: d

<interactive>:2:21: error: Variable not in scope: e

<interactive>:2:23: error: Variable not in scope: f
```

But when I check the type of lastButOne it looks like I'm giving it the correct input type, namely a list:

```
lastButOne :: [a] -> a
```

Is there an error in my code or am I trying to use the program incorrectly?

Comment: Are you trying to provide a string? Then you need to use `lastButOne "abcdef"`. At the moment you are providing a list of variables `[a, b, c, d, e ,f]` but none of those have been defined anywhere.

Comment: What do you think "`Variable not in scope: a`" means?

Comment: Expressed another way: Remember `"abcdef"` is sugar for `['a','b','c','d','e','f']`--  you need single quotes to name the `Char`s. `a` is being rejected an an undefined expression or "variable", but `'a'` is predefined as a name of a letter.

Comment: If you are new, I'd recommend that you forget about `head,tail`. These functions will crash your program when the list is empty, so are best to be avoided. Also, `length xs == 2` will scan the whole list, which is quite inefficient when you only need to scan the first 3 elements, at most, to perform the same check. Learn how to use pattern matching instead. E.g. `lastButOne [x1,x2] = x1 ; lastButOne (x:xs) = lastButOne xs`. Further, note that this function will crash on lists of length 1 or 0, and as such it is as dangerous as `head,tail`. I wouldn't use it in more "serious" code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't the type, it's that none of the variables `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` exist. You can't use variables that don't exist.

Comment: I see now. I didn't know that the program would interpret a,b,c... as variables, not just characters.

Comment: @Zermelo's_Choice If you want characters, surround them with `'`s. Or just use string literal syntax (`"abcdef"`, which is a shortcut for `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`).